# iOS css -webkit-transform: scale doesn't offset touch events

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile-safari

I have an iframe I need to pull in for display on iOS devices. The contents of the iframe are not under my control and they are not responsive in any way (fixed 800x600). So I'd like to scale the iframe down to display it in the iOS viewport.

Using `-webkit-transform: scale(0.4)` I was able to scale it down but now the touch events are all wrong (e.g. touch a form element doesn't pop open the keyboard). If you touch where the element was before scaling it works.

Is there any way to correct the offset for touch events?

Comment: Hey jckdnk111, did you ever resolve this issue? I'm looking into this now. Can you update with an answer if you resolved it?

Comment: I never solved it. In the end I had ask the owner of the iframe URL to create a postMessage API so I could ask the page to scale itself down (e.g. using a transform on the body of the document in the iframe). It is hacky but it works -- if you can't ask the iframe page to scale itself then I'm afraid you might just be out of luck.

Answer (score 7):

Opt for `scale3d` instead of `scale`. In my experience, transforming elements that need to be responsive was better achieved when the element was pushed into the accelerated stack.

#### Markup

```
<iframe src="http://wikipedia.org" width="200" height="200"/>
```

#### CSS

```
iframe {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.4,0.4,0.4);
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gyHR6/

---

More about `-webkit-transform-style` here:
https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/transform-style.html

Comment: Scale3d doesn't seem to affect the touch area. It actually just makes the image blurry in our case.

Comment: Can you post your event handler(s) for touchstart, etc. ?

Comment: Both `-webkit-transform: scale()` and `scale3d()` work perfectly fine on iframes, so long as you are scaling the iframe down. If you scale it up the click areas do not scale past 1x. Demo here: http://adexcite.com/iframe_scaling_test.html

Comment: This fixed my iOS8 problem; upon adding a 2d scale, touch events wouldn't fire. Now with a 3d scale, everything works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Seems this problem is still present in iOS 9. When scaling an iframe up every touch event stop working. Meh.