# "-webkit-transform: scale(2)" doesn't affect click area of Facebook Like Button (on iPad)

Tags: css, ipad, iframe, safari, scale

I've transformed size of iframe with like:

[image: Scaled facebook like button]

```
iframe
{
    transform: scale(2) !important; 
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) !important; 
    transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
}
```

For all desktop browsers it works just fine, but in iPad Safari clickable area of links stay just the same size (look at third picture)

Does anybody know how it can be fixed?

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156851/ios-css-webkit-transform-scale-doesnt-offset-touch-events

Comment: Hey meatinside, did you ever resolve this issue? I'm looking into this now. Can you update with an answer if you resolved it?

Comment: djburdick, no, i haven't found any solutions

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the 'clip:' attribute?

ie:  clip: rect(3px 20px 5px 8px);

Sorry if that's too much of a workaround.